# Adding ACES False Color to Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Does anyone know of a way to add False Colour back into Blender when switching to ACES Colour Management?

Thanks,
Mitchell

Answer (score 2):

After messing with ACES configs a little, I got it to work. Please note that I am by no means a pro colourist and can't really say if it's 100% accurate. Described steps are working for *Blender 2.93* and *ACES 1.2*.

In short, you need to copy two luts (`filmic_desat65cube.spi3d` and `filmic_false_color.spi3d`) from Blender's [built-in luts](https://github.com/blender/blender/tree/master/release/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic) to `<your ACES config directory>/luts` folder. Then, modify your OCIO config by copying three colorspaces (*Linear*, *Filmic Log* and *False Color*) from [Blender's default config](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/release/datafiles/colormanagement/config.ocio). Finally, add `- !<View> {name: False Color, colorspace: False Color}` in `displays` property and `False Colors` in `active_views`.

In details:

1. Open Blender's filmic luts on [Github](https://github.com/blender/blender/tree/master/release/datafiles/colormanagement/filmic).
2. Open, then press *Download* button on the right side for `filmic_desat65cube.spi3d` and `filmic_false_color.spi3d`.
3. Open ACES config directory on your computer.

   If you don't know where it is and have system variable OCIO setup, on Windows you can press `Win+R` and  type

   ```
    "C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
   ```

   and find the path to ACES config in the upper section. It will look similar to `C:\OCIO\aces_1.2\config.ocio`.
4. Copy downloaded files to `luts` folder in ACES config directory.
5. Open `config.ocio` itself in a text editor.
6. Create config backup file `backup_config.ocio` and copy all contents in there. If you are using default ACES config, you can just rely on [OCIO github](https://github.com/colour-science/OpenColorIO-Configs/blob/feature/aces-1.2-config/aces_1.2/config.ocio) for the backup.
7. Open [Blender's default OCIO config](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/release/datafiles/colormanagement/config.ocio).
8. Find and copy three `- !<ColorSpace>` blocks of code named *Linear*, *Filmic Log* and *False Color*. You can easily find them with `name: Linear` and so on. Paste it in your `config.ocio` at the very end.
9. Scroll to the upper part of your config. There should be a bunch of lines starting with `- !<View>`.

   Add following line:

   ```
        - !<View> {name: False Color, colorspace: False Color}
   ```
10. Not far from there should be `active_views` property, add `False Color` at any place at the list.
11. In Blender go to `Render Properties -> Color Management`. If `Display Device` set to `ACES` and you have `False Color` in `View Transform` dropdown transforming color as expected, you've succeeded. If you are having a hard time editing config, you can try ready-to-go configs: [default config](https://github.com/svetaet/aces-with-false-colors/blob/main/config.ocio) or [Blender optimized config with redundant entries removed](https://github.com/svetaet/aces-blender-optimized/blob/main/config.ocio).

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a sample config](https://github.com/Ginurx/Blender-ACES-Config) with all blender's default display transforms being retained.
https://github.com/Ginurx/Blender-ACES-Config